# Magento 1.8 - Redirect after admin login based on role?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I would like different user roles to see different things when they log in. How can this be achieved?

I assume it would be something like:

```
<?php
$adminrole = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole();

if ($adminrole["role_id"] == "5")

{

header( 'Location: /admin/some_url' ) ; 

}

else 

{

header( 'Location: /admin/some_other_url' ) ;

}

?>
```

But I have to be honest, I'm not sure where this should go or even if it is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create admin login observer module for this redirection.

This link will teach how to create observer module http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

This link will teach about how to create admin login observer module http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/272522/ In observer function you can add your redirection code.